# PHP Session Cookie With Security Flags & Extendable Expiry - Best Way?

Tags: php, authentication, session, cookies, logout

Okay so I've created a login system using PHP Sessions which stores user-related data within $_SESSION while logged in. To reach a PHP $_SESSION / session cookie whose expiry gets extended by `x` seconds every time the client refreshes a page, I created the following callback, which I call upon every page initiation:

```
<?php

if ( session_status() ===  PHP_SESSION_NONE ) {

  session_start(
    [
      'cookie_path' => '/',
      'cookie_domain' => 'mydomain.com',
      'cookie_secure' => true,
      'cookie_httponly' => true,
      'cookie_samesite' => 'Strict',
      'use_strict_mode' => true,
      'use_trans_sid' => false,
      'use_only_cookies' => true
    ]
  );

} else {

  // If session already exists, simply take it up again without overwriting parameters
  session_start();

}

// Then determine the lifetime of the cookie (was only able to make the session cookie
// lifetime expendable using this syntax, as explained in the [first example of the php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)
setcookie(
  session_name(),
  session_id(),
  [
    'expires' => time() + x,
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => 'mydomain.com',
    'secure' => true,
    'httponly' => true,
    'samesite' => 'Strict'
  ]
);

?>
```

The reason why I specify all the:

- httponly
- secure
- cookie path
- cookie domain
- samesite

parameters upon the very first call of `session_start()` AND also in the call of `setcookie()` is because if I specify one of them in `session_start()` and not in `setcookie()` or vice-versa, the browser returns two session cookies with the same session IDs, one having all of the mentioned flags, and the other without:

[image: Here you can see the two identic session IDs]

[image: And here you can see how one took up all of the parameters and the other didn't]

Now the problem is that, when I logout via the following callback, which I call as specified in the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.session-destroy):

```
<?php 

// Called via PHP Form Submit

session_start();

setcookie(
  session_name(),
  '',
  time() - 42000,
  '/',
  'mydomain.com',
  true,
  true
);

session_destroy();

header( 'Location: mydomain.com' );

?>
```

I get the same problem as described in the images above; two session cookies in my browser, and again one having all the flags set, the other not, and the one without the flags set having set its expiry to the session's end, and the other one with its expiry set in x seconds; all exactly as in the image.

What am I doing wrong?

***UPDATE***

Is it may better to actually set all of the session cookie parameters via the `php.ini` file, and handle the session cookie expiry via a timestamp within $_SESSION, done like in [this example](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.session-regenerate-id.php)?? Just thinking of a way of making the provision of any parameters in `session_start()` + any calls to `setcookie()` obsolete..

So my question is basically:

***What's actually the best way of using several PHP session cookie flags, combined with a session expiry which is limited to let's say 10 mins, which gets refreshed by 10 mins on every page load?***

Comment: I never encountered any case where you need to start the session and manually set the session cookie. I'd say that this is the root cause of your issue.

Comment: Well as stated, I do it that way to extend the session cookie's lifetime on page refreshes while simultaneously adding all of the mentioned session cookie flags. If you know about a way to do both of this without using ```setcookie()``` as the most upvoted example on the [phpdocs](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) states, let me know! :')